# USB Stick with write-protection

Tags: usb-drive, attack-vector

I bought a USB stick with a hardware switch to enable write protection. I burned a Linux iso on it to make some forensics analysis on my installed OS. Could the write protection be bypassed via software from a remote attacker? Could it be attacked and re-written?

Comment: Sort of related: The write protect switch on normal SD cards *definitely* doesn't prevent writes. It just sets a bit that the OS is supposed to honor. (No idea about USB drives. Even though such switches don't seem standard, I wouldn't cite that as proof that a USB drive enforces write protection. And I hope someone else wouldn't accept something that weak as proof.)

Comment: Depending upon the details of exactly how you "*burned a Linux iso on it*", it's likely a **SquashFS Read Only** file system anyway. Rewriting it even with write access would not be easy.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether that switch makes a change to the hardware or it triggers a software change in the stick (or the OS).

Any software-based protection could be manipulated via software. Hardware-based protection cannot be manipulated via software.

Comment: How can I know if the switch is a real hardware or it triggers a software change ?  If I try to mount it on openbsd with write protection enabled I can't because the os says "permission denied"

Comment: @BiosRootKit There is probably no way for someone to tell without reverse engineering the USB. I think you only need to worry about software on the OS computer. Unless there's something I'm unaware of, like being able to reprogram the USB firmware over USB.

Comment: what's do you mean with "software on the OS computer" ? I have that usb stick that seems hacked... If I boot from the USB I don't think that the OS software can interfere with the usb stick. The only alternative is the usb firmware reprogrammed or some malware in the laptop firmware.